# Wp8 cell tower information

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, cellid

On windows phone 8, is there any api to get the nearest cell tower information? like cell id, location area code etc...

Comment: have you found a solution to your question yet??

Comment: This question would be better placed in https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Windows Phone 8 API doesn't provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

Any updates in WP 8.1?

The best I have found so far:

```
NetworkInterfaceList networkInterfaceList = new NetworkInterfaceList();
foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo networkInterfaceInfo in networkInterfaceList)
{
    if (networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceSubtype == NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_HSPA)
    {...}
}
```

But it's not MCC, MNC, LAC, CellID level data.